# How to Capture Key combination ALT+CTRL+INSERT using preTranslate message in C++

Tags: c++, key

I want to capture key combinations like `ALT+CTRL+INSERT` using `preTranslateMessage()` in C++ as shown in below code. I could not get what I am expecting. I tried doing logical code changes. 
It doesnt seems to be the best solution.Also,using Keyboard Accelerators may solve my problem.But I could not exactly figure out how to do process.

Please anyone suggest me some possible solution..

```
BOOL BMWView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    //static int k_ctrlPressed,k_altPressed,k_insertPressed = 0;
       static int keylog_var = 0;
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYUP )
    {
       switch (pMsg->wParam)
       {  

            case VK_CONTROL: if(keylog_var==0) keylog_var = 1; else keylog_var = 0;
                break;
            case VK_MENU:    if(keylog_var==1) keylog_var = 2; else keylog_var = 0;
                break;
            case VK_INSERT:  if(keylog_var==2) keylog_var = 3; else keylog_var = 0;
                break; 
            default: keylog_var = 0;        
                break;
       }
    //Switch case is replaced with below if statement 

    if(keylog_var == 3)
     {  
        keylog_var = 0;
         // Set mode
        CWnd *pWnd = (CWnd *)this;
        pWnd->PostMessage(ID_ENTRY, 0L, 0L);
    }

  }
    return BView::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
```

Comment: Using accelerators would indeed be the cleanest solution. You should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Capture a `ALT+CTRL+INSERT` with `GetKeyState` and test `pMsg` for a `VK_INSERT`.

```
 BOOL CTestView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
 {
  if(pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN)
  {
   BOOL bCtrl=::GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)&0x8000;
   BOOL bShift=::GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)&0x8000;
   BOOL bAlt=::GetKeyState(VK_MENU)&0x8000;

   switch(pMsg->wParam)
   {
      case VK_INSERT :
        if( bCtrl && bAlt )    
        {
          MessageBox(" Ctrl+Alt+INSERT ", " ",MB_OK);
        }

      break;

   }
  }
  return CView::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
 }
```